# VBA Remove Columns and Strings in excel

Tags: excel, vba, edit, auto

I am working in a VBA Code that will remove unnecesary columns upon certain conditions

```
Dim keepColumn As Boolean
Dim currentColumn As Integer
Dim columnHeading As String

currentColumn = 1
While currentColumn <= ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    columnHeading = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value

    'CHECK WHETHER TO KEEP THE COLUMN
    keepColumn = False
    If columnHeading = "Agent" Then keepColumn = True
    If columnHeading = "Interval" Then keepColumn = True
    If columnHeading = "Break Time" Then keepColumn = True
    If columnHeading = "Staffed Time" Then keepColumn = True
    If columnHeading = "Lunch Time" Then keepColumn = True
    If columnHeading = "Email Time" Then keepColumn = True
    If columnHeading = "System Time" Then keepColumn = True
    If columnHeading = "Personal Time" Then keepColumn = True


    If keepColumn Then
    'IF YES THEN SKIP TO THE NEXT COLUMN,
        currentColumn = currentColumn + 1
    Else
    'IF NO DELETE THE COLUMN
        ActiveSheet.Columns(currentColumn).Delete
    End If

    'LASTLY AN ESCAPE IN CASE THE SHEET HAS NO COLUMNS LEFT
    If (ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address = "$A$1") And (ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1").Text = "") Then Exit Sub
Wend
```

The second part of the codes requires to do 2 things,   removes from column A,  all characters  but the letters, and also in column B changes 05/04/2021 00:00 -0600 - 05/05/2021 00:00 -0601 to  just 05/04/21 (meaning,  removes evrything after first space), this second part does take a while and I will like to make it faster. Any suggestions?

Function

```
`Function cleanString(str As String) As String
        Dim ch, bytes() As Byte: bytes = str
    For Each ch In bytes
        If Chr(ch) Like "[A-Za-z]" Then cleanString = cleanString & Chr(ch)
    Next ch
End Function`
```

And here is when i want to run it

```
 Dim rng As Range

For Each rng In Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A5000").Cells 'adjust sheetname and range accordingly
    rng.Value = cleanString(rng.Value)
Next

Dim r As Range

For Each r In Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    r.Value = Split(r.Value, " ")(0)
Next r
```

Finally  I will like to  run the code automatically when  the info is updated

Comment: `I will like to make it faster. Any suggestions?` Read the range into an array and then perform the cleanup. It will be superfast!

Comment: Does this work, and you're asking for tips on efficiency? [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be the better place to ask.

Comment: Not actually. It is on topic for both sites. :) You may want to see [Please stop redirecting performance problems to Code Review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388864/please-stop-redirecting-performance-problems-to-code-review) and [Performance question - Stack Overflow or Code Review?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300981/performance-question-stack-overflow-or-code-review) and [Guidance on migrating questions to Code Review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348395/guidance-on-migrating-questions-to-code-review) @BruceWayne

Comment: @BruceWayne Even I used to think that but was later corrected. If you have enough reputation then you will be able to see the [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390803/is-this-question-on-topic-for-code-review) that I had asked (now deleted)

Answer (score 0):

> I will like to make it faster. Any suggestions?

Like I mentioned, read the range into an array and then perform the cleanup. It will be superfast!

**LOGIC**

1. Find last row in the relevant column
2. Store the range values in array
3. Perform the actions on the array rather than doing it directly on the range. For example extract alpha chars or getting part of a string. Remember to prefix the date part with `'` to prevent Excel from auto formatting.

**CODE**

Here is an example. I have commented the code so if you get stuck then simply ask.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wsInput As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim MyAr As Variant
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet which has data
    Set wsInput = Sheet1
    
    '~~> This is where the output will be dumped.
    Set wsOutput = Sheet2
    
    With wsInput
        '~~> Find last row in Col A
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        '~~> Store the range values in array
        MyAr = .Range("A1:B" & lRow).Value2
        
        '~~> perform the actions on the array
        For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
            '~~> Extract alpha chars
            MyAr(i, 1) = GetAlphaChars(MyAr(i, 1))
            
            '~~> Get the part before string. and prefix with ' to
            '~~> prevent Excel from auto formatting
            If InStr(1, MyAr(i, 2), " ") Then MyAr(i, 2) = "'" & Split(MyAr(i, 2), " ")(0)
        Next i
    End With
    
    '~~> Send the output
    wsOutput.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(MyAr), 2).Value = MyAr
End Sub

'~~> Function to extract Alpha characters from the string
Private Function GetAlphaChars(cellVal As Variant) As String
    Dim regX As Object
    
    Set regX = CreateObject("VBScript.Regexp")
    
    With regX
        .Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z]+"
        .Global = True
        GetAlphaChars = .Replace(cellVal, vbNullString)
    End With
End Function
```

**IN ACTION**

[image]

Comment: Awesome,   Is there a way to apply it  directly on the same sheet, or it will be better  to dump the new info into a new one

Comment: It can be dumped in the same sheet simply change `wsOutput.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(MyAr), 2).Value = MyAr` to `wsInput.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(MyAr), 2).Value = MyAr`. Note: Create a backup before you work with the above code.